# PHP ban list making

Tags: php

I have two files: index.php and ban.php.

I want to IP ban anyone who visits ban.php from using index.php.

I cannot use mysql (load issue) or let the php write to `.httaccess` (security issue).

How would you solve this?

Comment: Can you write to any files?  How about using the session?

Comment: Quick and Dirty: write to cookie in ban.php, read from cookie in index.php and redirect if cookie is set

Comment: Session won't help here.

Comment: You can't use a database, you can't use `.htaccess`, can you write PHP code? Is that acceptable?

Comment: writing to file is allowed, cookie is bad - because we'll be banning bots too, session is too short term, writing PHP code is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add the IP address to a file you can access from both files, for example:

**ban.php**

```
<?php
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   // get the ip
$list  = file_get_contents('ipbans.txt');
$list .= $ipAddress . '\n';  
file_put_contents('ipbans.txt', $list);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$file = file('ipbans.txt');
foreach ($file as $line)
{
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $line) {
        die; // or header('Location:') or something...
    }
}
```

This doesn't check for duplicates so anyone who would visit `ban.php` multiple times would get their IP added several times. This is trivial to check for (in `ban.php`) and so I left it to you as an exercise.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Create banlist.txt

```
<?
// In ban.php
$fp = fopen('banlist.txt','a+');
fwrite($fp,$USER_IP);
?>

<?
// In index.php
$list = file(banlist.txt);
if(in_array($USER_IP,$list)){
    header('Location:ban.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Although this would work (same as vanneto's solution), it won't scale very well once the list becomes a few thousand records long ( thats thousands of string comparisons per request, banned or not ). Instead you can do a simple string search if instead of using file() you do: $is_banned = ( strpos( file_get_contents("banlist.txt"), $USER_IP ) !== false );    .. Cheers